# Android NDK - problems with example (UnsatisfiedLinkError)

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to run and understand ths example: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2689-how-to-use-the-android-ndk-to-improve-performance/

It's a quite simple example with the following files:

```
FibActivity.java - main activity file
FibLib - class implementing and calling the native functions
fib.c - the C source file with the native functions and code
FibLib.h - the C header file, automatically created from the FibLib class
Android.mk - the makefile
```

I've implemented the example exactly as described. Still, when I run it, I get this (UnsatisfiedLinkError) error when the app tries to access the native code:

```
12-21 11:31:53.042: D/dalvikvm(1491): Trying to load lib /data/data
/com.frank.android.ndk/lib/libfib.so 0x405143b8
12-21 11:31:53.042: D/dalvikvm(1491): Added shared lib /data/data/com.frank.android.ndk
/lib/libfib.so 0x405143b8
12-21 11:31:53.042: D/dalvikvm(1491): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data
/com.frank.android.ndk/lib/libfib.so 0x405143b8, skipping init
12-21 11:31:53.093: W/dalvikvm(1491): No implementation found for native Lcom/frank
/android/ndk/FibLib;.fibN (I)J
12-21 11:31:53.102: D/AndroidRuntime(1491): Shutting down VM
12-21 11:31:53.102: W/dalvikvm(1491): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught 
exception (group=0x40015560)
12-21 11:31:53.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1491): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 11:31:53.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1491): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: fibN
12-21 11:31:53.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1491): at 
com.frank.android.ndk.FibLib.fibN(Native Method)
12-21 11:31:53.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1491): at 
com.frank.android.ndk.JavaNativeFibonacciAct
ivity.onClick(JavaNativeFibonacciActivity.java:52)
```

The only strange thing I notice is, according to the logcat, that eclipse tries to load the library from the /lib folder, while the automatically created folder is called /libs. However, renaming the /lib folder to /libs and rebuilding everything makes no difference.

Anyone got any ideas? I've been trying for days to get examples to work that include using javah to create a header file. Creating only the main activity and the c file, and then calling the native code from the main activity seems to work, but as soon as I begin using header file(s) I get the UnsatisfiedLinkError.

UPDATE:

From FibLib.java:

```
// Native implementation
static {
    System.loadLibrary("fib"); // 
}

// Native implementation - recursive
public static native long fibN (int n);

// Native implementation - iterative
public static native long fibNI (int n);
```

The fib.c file:

```
#include "com_frank_android_ndk_FibLib.h" /*  */

/* Recursive Fibonacci Algorithm  */
long fibN(long n) {
    if(n<=0) return 0;
    if(n==1) return 1;
    return fibN(n-1) + fibN(n-2);
}

/* Iterative Fibonacci Algorithm  */
long fibNI(long n) {
    long previous = -1;
    long result = 1;
    long i=0;
    int sum=0;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        sum = result + previous;
        previous = result;
        result = sum;
    }

    return result;
}

/* Signature of the JNI method as generated in header file  */
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_frank_android__ndk_fibN (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jlong  n) {
    return fibN(n);
}

/* Signature of the JNI method as generated in header file  */
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_frank_android__ndk_fibNI (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jlong  n) {
    return fibNI(n);
}
```

The Andoid.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := fib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := fib.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: have you complied the JNi Code Using ndk-build ?

Comment: Yes. No errors there, and the file fiblib.so is present under /libs/armeabi (automatically created folder).

Comment: Can you post your Android.mk file?

Comment: Where do you have the header file located (FibLib.h)? Depending on where you have it you'll need to add the location to your Android.mk, e.g. LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

Comment: It's in the /jni folder, which should be ok I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Java package name appears to be named "com.frank.android.ndk" and your Java class name appears to be named "FibLib" and in turn the name of the C function matching FibN should be Java_com_frank_android_ndk_FibLib_fibN.  This [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp615) is referened by the Android docs and details the JNI naming convention for C functions.

Comment: Thanks, man. A simple case of type error, even though I went over it several times. Of course - the C function was named fiblib instead of FibLib.

Answer (score 1):

Does it only seem, or your C function names really use double underscore before word ndk? It should be single underscore IMHO.

Comment: Good question. Yes, it did. I changed it though, and recompiled the file. Still gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It can't find `Lcom/frank/android/ndk/FibLib;.fibN`.  The log indicates that the library was loaded successfully.

The method should be called `Java_com_frank_android_ndk_FibLib_fibN`; in the question you have a double underscore and you're missing the class name.  If you have two different methods that resolve to the same thing, you can differentiate them by encoding the arguments as well, but that doesn't seem necessary here.

You said this is a C program, but sometimes people conflate C and C++, so I'll also point out that if this is a ".cpp" file you'll need to put `extern "C"` in the declaration or C++ will "mangle" the function name.

See also http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_ULE

Answer (score 0):

have you complied the JNi Code Using ndk-build ?
the class Name Should be same as Described in JNI  and in Java

```
Java_com_qualcomm_QCARSamples_VideoPlayback_VideoPlayback_initApplicationNative
```

the initApplicationNative is method name that should be same on both Java and JNi 
if not then you will get this error

Comment: I've compiled the fib.c source file, yes, and the file libfib.so is present in the /libs/armeabi (automatically created) folder. See UPDATE above - I've included the contents of FibLib.java and fib.c

Comment: parameters are not the same in JNI its long and in java u are using Int

Comment: Yah, I see that. However, that shouldn't have anything to do with the links? Anyway - I changed the native implementation in the java code from int to long. No changed.

Comment: try to use jobject rather than jclass

Comment: No, it needs to be jclass as it is a static method.  The real problem, as Alex pointed out, is the double underscore.